# Task 'run' not found in root project '...'

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I've imported a project from someone who exported it from IntelliJ.
The project is compiled with Gradle.

Here is a screenshot from is computer:
[image]

and now here is a screenshot from my computer:

[image]

I see have don't have all external libraries.

And the most important is he can run the project by clicking the green arrow on right top of the screen (as we can see on the screen)

But I can't... I tried to manually run "build" from Gradle task view. It works.
But when I try to run "run" from the Gradle task view I have an error:

[image]

The code works and all I want is just to run it... Please help, I really need to work on it...